# Regex with mix quantifiers

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to validate a telephone number in an ASP.Net MVC application using RegEx validation annotation.

Apart from allowed characters and max-min length, **I want to allow maximum 2 spaces anywhere in the text**. I have tried the following RegEx but its not working.

```
^(\+)?(\d|\s{0,2}|-|\(|\)){8,16}$
```

It works fine if I remove {0,2} without validating number of spaces.

I had tried different combination but no luck.

**Update**

"1234 5 6" should be valid but "123 4 5 6" should not.

Comment: Are the whitespace counted as one of the `{8,16}` chars ?

Comment: Works for me with numbers like 1-123-456-7890  What phone formats are you trying to handle?

Comment: If not, then this is the one you need `^(?!.*\s{3})(\+)?(?:\s*(\d|-|[()])\s*){8,16}$`

Comment: @sln yes. Dweeberly I also need to allow spaces but max two.

Comment: @Alpesh - max is 2, then I just posted a regex. Btw, the whitespace is counted as a character ? Are you sure ?

Comment: @sln I need min 0  to max 2 spaces. Ya they are counted as part of 8-16 length. That's what I have been asked for.

Comment: @Alpesh - Posted it, echo in here. Re-do the math not counting wsp as a character, use a different max range.

Comment: Try [`@"^(?!(?:\S*\s){3})(?=(?:\D*\d){8,16}\D*$)\+?[\d\s()-]+$"`](https://regex101.com/r/gtPozk/2)

Comment: @sln it works for consecutive spaces not for scattered spaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works fine but spaces are not counted as part of max-min leangth (8-16). From the expression I can see why. But not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What should be counted in `{8,16}`? Try [`^(?!(?:\S*\s){3})(?=.{8,16}$)\+?[\d\s()-]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/gtPozk/3)

Comment: Updated my question with an example. Thank you for your help so far guys.

Comment: Updated the demo link - https://regex101.com/r/gtPozk/4

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works perfectly. Thank you RegEx guru. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Alpesh -  `it works for consecutive spaces not for scattered spaces` – `^(?!.*\s{3})\+?(?:\s*[\d()-]\s*){8,16}$` I'm pretty sure you either don't know regular expressions, didn't try it, or just plain feeble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider the following pattern:

```
^(?!(?:\S*\s){3})(?=.{8,16}$)\+?[\d\s()-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gtPozk/4).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:\S*\s){3})` - no 3 or more whitespace chars after any non-whitespace chars are allowed
- `(?=.{8,16}$)` - the string length must be from 8 to 16 (no line breaks, or replace `.` with `[\s\S]`)
- `\+?` - an optional `+`
- `[\d\s()-]+` - 1 or more digits, whitespaces, `(`, `)`, `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What to do if I don't want to count + as part of 8-16 length?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew your answer works for two consecutive spaces e.g `12346  7812345` but as I understand this should be incorrect?

Comment: @Alpesh Put it at the start of the regex.

Comment: @HusseinGolshani Two consecutive spaces are not forbidden. The rule is *0 to 2 spaces are allowed anywhere in the string*.

Comment: @HusseinGolshani good point but two consecutive spaces are fine for now. I just don't want users to enter too many spaces.

Comment: @Alpesh, Also adding `(?:\S*\s{2})` will prevent consecutive spaces in the above answer. `^(?!(?:\S*\s){3}|(?:\S*\s{2}))(?=.{8,16}$)\+?[\d\s()-]+$`

Comment: @HusseinGolshani To disallow consecutive spaces, add `(?!.*\s{2})` after `^`. However, it is also possible to do without lookarounds. `^(?!(?:\S*\s){3})(?=.{8,16}$)\+?[\d()-]+(?:\s[\d()-]+)*$`